# Nokogiri и вывод одного значения массива

Tags: php, массивы, nokogiri

Всем привет использую nokogiri для работы с авито.
Имеется вот такая конструкция:

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.avito.ru/krasnodar/vakansii');
$saw = new nokogiri($html);
echo '<pre>';
foreach($saw->get('.breadcrumbs-link-count') as $item){
    print_r($item);
}
echo '</pre>';
```

На выходе вижу вот что:

```
Array (
  [class] => breadcrumbs-link-count
  [#text] => Array (
    [0] => 4 940
   )
)
```

Как мне вывести не всю эту красоту, а только цифры 4 940?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так, например:

```
print_r($item['#text'][0]);
```

Comment: Супер! Вы мне очень помогли! Перепробовал кучу вариантов, до такого не додумался. Спасибо огромное